# Creating a Function with the Map Method (Colt Steele Web Developer Bootcamp)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, methods

Ok so here's the question prompt

[image]

Here's my code:

```
function cleanNames(array) {
array.map(function (n) {
    return n.trim();
})}
```

I get undefined everytime that I try to test it my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return array.map...`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting **undefined** is that you are not returning anything in cleanNames function you just run the map method on 'array', the analogy is that you actually process the array but its result is not used anywhere, so it's like disappeared into thin air.

So the code should look like this:

```
function cleanNames(array) {
   return array.map(function (n) {
       return n.trim();
})}
```

Comment: Thank you for the analogy. It helps me to conceptualize as opossed to blindly copying the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code

```
  function cleanNames(array) {
  return  array.map(function (n) {
        return n.trim();
    })
}
```